# Python webdriver TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrap information from the website, I use spyder(python 3.9)

```
http://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/#hs_z
```

And I tried:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-notification")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
options.add_argument("--headless")
url = 'http://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/mkt/#hs_z'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(./chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputSuggest"]').clear()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inputSuggest"]').send_keys('22粤科02')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SSForm"]/input[3]').click()
```

And got:

```
line 255, in start_session
    self.session_id = response['sessionId'] 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The remote code is

```
 def start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile=None):
    
        if not isinstance(capabilities, dict):
            raise InvalidArgumentException("Capabilities must be a dictionary")
        if browser_profile:
            if "moz:firefoxOptions" in capabilities:
                capabilities["moz:firefoxOptions"]["profile"] = browser_profile.encoded
            else:
                capabilities.update({'firefox_profile': browser_profile.encoded})
        w3c_caps = _make_w3c_caps(capabilities)
        parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
                      "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
        if 'sessionId' not in response:
            response = response['value']
        self.session_id = response['sessionId']
        self.capabilities = response.get('value')
```

Not sure what causes the error, and the website does not open

Comment: Whats the error stack?

Comment: Can this be caused by missing quote here: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(./chromedriver.exe',options=options)`? Should be `'./chromedriver.exe'`